# How to use a function variable from **kwargs in python?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I am trying to do the following, but am getting an exception **NameError("global name 'rid' is not defined",**

```
def safe_forcecall(fn):
    def _safe_forcecall(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._token_valid(rid) is not None:
            return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return _safe_forcecall


@safe_forcecall
def add_booking(self, rid, data):
    ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing in `rid` as a *positional* argument, so can be found in `args` instead:

```
if self._token_valid(args[0]) is not None:
```

If your decorator always needs access to that argument, just name it explicitly:

```
def safe_forcecall(fn):
    def _safe_forcecall(self, rid, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._token_valid(rid) is not None:
            return fn(self, rid, *args, **kwargs)
    return _safe_forcecall
```

You won't find the value in the `kwargs` dictionary; only if you were to call `add_booking` with a `rid=rid` argument would it be placed there. By using an explicit `rid` argument in your decorator wrapper function, you make sure it is always bound to the `rid` name.

Comment: Thanks! what if I need to make rid optional? is the best way to do it is to define _safe_forcecall(self, rid=None, ...)  and then to check if it is not None?

Comment: @AviMeir: In your decorated function `rid` is not optional. That'd be your first port of call, making it a keyword argument with a default value. Then you can test to see if it is passed in to your decorator wrapper with `if 'rid' in kwargs`.

Comment: Well, assuming I want to change it to make it optional. Could I do it this way? Is it best practice to instead do something like: if 'rid' in kwargs:
                lcode = kwargs['rid']
            else:
                lcode = 0

Comment: @AviMeir: You'd use `lcode = kwargs.get('rid', 0)`, e.g. ask the dictionary for the key, specifying a default if not set.